# Where can I go to change the Terms and Conditions on DNN 9?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

Where can I go to change the Terms as well as the Privacy policy in DNN 9?
In previous version you could go the Languages option to change this, but DNN 9 does not have an international Language team to work on this anymore. Where to go now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Manage > Sites`. Then select your portal settings by clicking it's settings icon.
In the Site Settings, go to the `Languages` and click the last icon after the Culture.
You then get to the `Translate Resources` tab and you can select the language file you want to edit.

You need the `GlobalResources.resx` > `MESSAGE_PORTAL_TERMS.Text` and `MESSAGE_PORTAL_PRIVACY.Text`

**Step 1**

[image]

**Step 2**

[image]

**Step 3**

[image]

Comment: I have made changed to the MESSAGE_PORTAL_TERMS.Text value and when I click on Save Translation To File and navigate to the terms page I noticed that the text did not change. What should I do for the changes to reflect?

Comment: It is working on my local machine.... Check the file permissions and emtpy the cache. Maybe that will help?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple page as well, just use the url "/terms" (for single language sites) or "/(language)/terms" (for multi language sites), then you can add an HTML module and write your terms as needed. The skin object is exactly pointing to that Url. You may hide the page from the menu as well, if you want.

Same for privacy declaration, the Url is then "/privacy" or "/(language)/privacy".

To change the Url of a page go to page settings :: Advanced :: S.E.O.

Happy DNNing!
Michael